# Typeahead in angular5

Tags: angularjs

I have a input tag as below, when the user starts typing I need to lookup a list of users from the database as typeahead, and when the user makes a selection the model needs to be available for save.

```
<input id="txtpreparer" type="text" class="validate form-control" required *ngIf="approval && approval.preparer" [(ngModel)]="approval.preparer.approvername" #approvername="ngModel" name="preparerapprovername">
```

I followed https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage 
How do I bind the textbox to the datasource and retain the two way binding at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use rxjs and the below html to make it work.

```html
<input id="txtpreparer" type="text" class="validate form-control" required *ngIf="approval && approval.preparer"
                                   [(ngModel)]="approval.preparer.user" #approvername="ngModel" name="preparerapprovername" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultFormatter]="formatter" [inputFormatter]="formatter">
```